# Problema con ExpandableListView en android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-listview

Resulta que al hacer una consulta determinada está me da los datos para hacer una Expandable List View, la primera vez que abro el Expandable List View se muestra como debería ser.

[image: Consulta perfecta]

Hasta ahí todo bien, pero cuando me desplazo hacia arriba se me descuadra todo el ExpandableListView y se me muestra de otra manera diferente de como me los muestra la primera vez.

[image: Consulta descuadrada]

Este es el código del Adapter correspondiente a la lista:

@Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                             boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

```
    //Recupero los valores del ArrayList Objetos
    final ObjetosHistorico childText = (ObjetosHistorico) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_lista_historico, null);
    }

    //Instanciamos el cardView
    CardView cardView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.cv_id);

    //Le ponemos el color de fondo al cardView instanciado anteriormente
    ctiMetodos.setBackgroundCardView(_context.getApplicationContext(),cardView);

    //Aquí instanciamos los elementos de la cabecera.
    TextView txtListChild = convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);

    TextView txtListChild2 = convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem2);

    TextView txtListChild3 = convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem3);

    TextView txtListChild4 = convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem4);

    TextView txtListChild5 = convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem5);

    TextView txtListChild6 = convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem6);

    TextView txtListChild7 = convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem7);

    TextView txtListChild8 = convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem8);

    TextView txtListFacturaDescrip = convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.lblListItemFactura);

    TextView txtListFechaDescrip = convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem2Fecha);

    //Instanciamos el linear layout para poder ponerlo en visible o en invisible, según el caso
    LinearLayout llSkyBlue = convertView.findViewById(R.id.ll_sky_blue);

    //Aqui le asigno el valor que ha leido la consulta y he introducido en el objeto
    txtListChild.setText(childText.texto1);
    txtListChild2.setText(childText.texto2);
    txtListChild3.setText(childText.texto3);
    txtListChild4.setText(childText.texto4);
    txtListChild5.setText(childText.texto5);
    txtListChild6.setText(childText.texto6);
    txtListChild7.setText(childText.texto7);
    txtListChild8.setText(childText.texto8);

    //Le pongo la "cabecera" y color de fondo a la primera linea de la factura
    //Si el texto 1 es igual, al número de documento anterior y la posición del hijo es mayor a la 1, pues entonces ocultamos la cabecera
    // ya que se trata del mismo número de documento.
    if(childText.texto1.equals(Variables.sFacturaAnteriorAdapter)  && childPosition > 0)
    {
        txtListFacturaDescrip.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        txtListFechaDescrip.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        txtListChild.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        txtListChild2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        llSkyBlue.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    else //si no cumple la condición, pues entonces el programa entra por esta parte y deja visible la parte de la cabecera.
    {
        txtListFacturaDescrip.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        txtListFechaDescrip.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        txtListChild.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        txtListChild2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }

    //La variable sFacturaAnteriorAdapter coge el valor del número del documento.
    Variables.sFacturaAnteriorAdapter = childText.texto1;

    Variables.groupPosition = groupPosition;
    Variables.childPosition = childPosition;


    //Devolvemos la vista.
    return convertView;
}
```

Creo que el problema radica en esta parte del código del adaptador.Gracias

Comment: Hola Sergio, comparando las imágenes , no veo donde se descuadra.

Comment: En la primera imagen si te fijas bien, te salen dos lineas de la factura con el mismo número, mientras que en la segunda imagen sale una linea de la factura por un lado y la otra linea de la factura por otro lado, repitiendo cabecera.